# Как получить название ряда в QTableWidget по его индексу?

Tags: python, pyqt5, текст, qtablewidget, qtablewidgetitem

Есть таблица, в которой 6 рядов. Каждый ряд имеет своё название.

Есть ли метод получить это название по индексу?

```
self.table = QTableWidget(self)
self.table. ...                    # метод для получение 4 ряда
```

Comment: Попробуйте следующие self.table.verticalHeaderItem(i).text(). Не работает в случае если имя раду не было присвоено

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вывести имя ряда можно с помощью метода `.verticalHeaderItem(i).text()`

Пример использования :

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(270, 270)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.tableWidget = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.tableWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 10, 250, 250))
        self.tableWidget.setObjectName("tableWidget")
        self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(0)
        self.tableWidget.setRowCount(0)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(2)
        self.tableWidget.setRowCount(2)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        item.setText('имя')
        self.tableWidget.setVerticalHeaderItem(1, item)

        print(self.tableWidget.verticalHeaderItem(1).text()) # < --- выводит имя ряда

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    Window1 = MainWindow()
    Window1.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 2):

> QTableWidgetItem *QTableWidget::[**verticalHeaderItem**](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtablewidget.html#verticalHeaderItem)(int row) const
>
> Возвращает элемент вертикального заголовка для строки row.

---

> QTableWidgetItem *QTableWidget::[**horizontalHeaderItem**](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtablewidget.html#horizontalHeaderItem)(int column) const
>
> Возвращает элемент горизонтального заголовка для столбца, столбца, если он был установлен; в противном случае возвращает nullptr.

---

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Widget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Widget, self).__init__(parent)
        self.tableWidget = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(5, 6)
        self.book_button = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Click me")
        self.book_button.clicked.connect(self.book_clicked)

        lay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        lay.addWidget(self.tableWidget)
        lay.addWidget(self.book_button)

        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderLabels("P1 P2 P3 P4 P5 P6".split())
        self.tableWidget.setVerticalHeaderLabels("C101 C214 C320 F04 E201".split())

        for i in range(self.tableWidget.rowCount()):
            for j in range(self.tableWidget.columnCount()):
                item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
                item.setFlags(item.flags() | QtCore.Qt.ItemIsUserCheckable)
                item.setCheckState(QtCore.Qt.Unchecked)
                self.tableWidget.setItem(i, j, item)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def book_clicked(self):
        items = []
        for i in range(self.tableWidget.rowCount()):
            for j in range(self.tableWidget.columnCount()):
                item = self.tableWidget.item(i, j)
                if item.checkState() == QtCore.Qt.Checked:
                    items.append(item)

        for it in items:
            r = it.row()
            c = it.column()
            v = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(c).text()
            h = self.tableWidget.verticalHeaderItem(r).text()
            print(h, v)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Widget()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]